# What is multi-prime RSA (RSA-MP)?

Tags: rsa, standards, multi-prime-rsa

I found some related question but no real explanation of what it is and when and why to use it. What are the benefits and downsides and is it recommended?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSA with composite numbers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/rsa-with-composite-numbers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any standards of multi-prime RSA key generation?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5416/are-there-any-standards-of-multi-prime-rsa-key-generation)

Comment: It's history and some benefits are also discussed here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14552/who-first-published-the-interest-of-more-than-two-prime-factors-in-rsa

Comment: Thank you! I had only found one of those question so far!

Comment: @Erwin Is your question answered by any of these Q/A's? If yes, which one. If no, what's missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi-prime RSA is simply using more than 2 prime numbers in generating RSA public key - The public modulus would have more than 2 factors.

We use it because it has more efficient key-generation and decryption/signing operation, which is the benefit of it.

The downside being it might be easier to factor a multi-prime RSA public key than a dual-prime one.

It's neither recommended or recommended against, it's simply an possible option without any endorsement.

Comment: note that the primes must be distinct.

Answer (score 2):

The security of Multi-prime RSA is analyzed in Jason Hinek's PhD Thesis which can be accessed at

- [On the Security of Some Variants of RSA, Jason Hinek, 2007](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/2988/mjhinek_PhD_thesis_2007.pdf?sequence=1)

In this thesis, Hinek writes

***...Considering all of the known attacks on multi-prime RSA (with or without CRT decryption), the evidence suggests that multi-prime RSA with a safe number of primes is no less secure than RSA...***

Comment: With "safe number of primes" essentially defined as "no less secure than (biprime) RSA", that conclusion is certainly true!

Comment: @fgrieu By "safe", he's referring back to the rest of the paper, *esp.* Tables `5.1` and `7.2`; it's not "only" trivially true.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: yes, table 5.1 is relevant. It's a (too) much shortened version of table 1 from cited [work](https://web.archive.org/web/20220421124856/http://cwcyrix.duckdns.org/ftp-archives/ftp.compaq.com/pub/solutions/CompaqMultiPrimeWP.pdf), correctly summarized. Indeed, if referring to this, the sentence is more than a tautology. Table 7.2 is about dual RSA, thus irrelevant to that citation.