# Has there ever been any real world consequences of using probabilistic primality tests for RSA or other similar systems?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

Considering the huge amount of RSA certs which have been generated, wouldn't there probably be a small number of certs where one of the primes which may have actually been a composite? Has this ever been a problem in the wild?

I think RSA with such a p & q will fail signature verification & decryption. So in these cases, I don't think the tools would give a proper error message & this may lead to a major confusion.

And if the composite number is in fact a Carmichael number, then I think RSA would work as intended, but would be less secure than it was intended to be.

I know what with enough rounds of the Miller-Rabin algorithm, the probability of something like happening is very small. But I am just wondering if it has happened & been detected

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/rsa-with-composite-numbers

Comment: You also need to multiply that by the probability of hitting a Carmichael number first, which is very very low on itself.

Comment: Usually the number of Miller-Rabin tests is set such that the error probability is *provably* below $2^{-80}$ (or even smaller), but the real error probability is likely much smaller than what one can prove.

Comment: And then you have to multiply by the probability that someone is trying to crack the communication of someone with the compromisable certificates.

Comment: PGP got by with something much weaker than Miller-Rabin (just the Fermat test with 2,3,5,7). I don't think that this ever led to any practical problem. You can fool such tests, but doing so by chance is very, very unlikely.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The probability of *accidentally* mistaking a composite for a prime, for a number that you chose yourself, is extremely low and quantifiable, as others have mentioned. This is the situation that is considered in the standard analysis of randomized primality tests.

However, there is also a problem of someone *maliciously* generating a composite that primality tests will mistake as a prime. This can happen with much higher probability. The paper [Prime and Prejudice](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/749) by Albrecht, Massimo, Paterson, and Somorovsky shows how to do such a thing. In particular, they show how to construct a 2048-bit composite that OpenSSL mistakes as prime with probability 1/16, even when ostensibly configured to detect primes with error $2^{-80}$. The paper also describes some problematic consequences of being able to generate composites of this form.

As far as I know, mainstream primality tests in crypto libraries have been fixed in response to this paper.

Answer (score 5):

I think, it's important to look what is "very small" here:

In [this paper](https://exploringnumbertheory.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/an-upper-bound-for-carmichael-numbers/) (example 6), it's written that for RSA$-2048$ that the probability a false-positive happens is upper bounded by $\frac{1}{10^{80}}$.

I've made the computation with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=256*%28%28exp%28-%28ln%282%5E%28256%29%29%29*ln%28ln%28ln%282%5E%28256%29%29%29%29%20/ln%28ln%282%5E%28256%29%29%29%29%29%29) for a smaller key (RSA$-512$):

It's upper bounded by $2^{-73}$, thus it seems also negligible for real-world use-case.